# VBA Excel Add A Values Field

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a values field to an existing `PivotTable`. I get the pivot table I want, but after it gets done compiling I get a Run-time error

> "1004" Application-defined or object-defined error

at the following line : `pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Hours"), SumofHours, xlSum`

Here is my code:

```
Workbooks.Open "file path..."
Worksheets("Mo Pivot Tbl").Activate

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Hours"), SumofHours, xlSum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your line:

```
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Hours"), SumofHours, xlSum
```

With:

```
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Hours"), "Sum of Hours", xlSum
```

**Bonus**: there is no need to `Activate` the worksheet, just use :

```
Set pt = Worksheets("Mo Pivot Tbl").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
```

Comment: @4m4d3u5 your'e welcome, mark as answer, see here how:  http://stackoverflow.com/tour